# SQL alias not working with LIKE query to search record

Tags: sql

I'm little confused why this simple SQL query is not working with alias to search record. There are two different tables named as 'account' and 'members'. I have written a sub query to count the total number of members from members table and more records from account table. So, here the like query is not working properly and getting error.

```
SELECT name, email, (SELECT Count(id) FROM members WHERE id = id) as totalMember, id

FROM account 

WHERE
(name LIKE '%sa%' OR email LIKE '%sa%' OR totalMember LIKE '%sa%' OR
 id LIKE '%sa%')
```

Please suggest me how can we write **LIKE** with alias?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `totalMember` is an integer (the result of a `count` call), it will never contain `sa`.

Comment: Yes, this will work if we type any integer value in search. The above is just an example with "sa". this could be 1 or to 2 or any numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting probably has to do with that both the `account` and `members` tables have a column called `id`.  To get around this, use aliases:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    a.email,
    (SELECT COUNT(m.id) FROM members m WHERE m.id = a.id) AS totalMember,
    a.id
FROM account a
WHERE
    (a.name LIKE '%sa%' OR a.email LIKE '%sa%' OR a.totalMember LIKE '%sa%' OR
     a.id LIKE '%sa%');
```

An alternative way to write your query would be to use a join between the two tables:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    a.email,
    COUNT(m.id) AS totalMember,
    a.id
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN members m
    ON a.id = m.id
WHERE
    (a.name LIKE '%sa%' OR a.email LIKE '%sa%' OR a.totalMember LIKE '%sa%' OR
     a.id LIKE '%sa%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Write something like this :

```
SELECT name, email, (SELECT Count(id) FROM members b WHERE b.id = a.id) as 
totalMember, id
FROM account a 
WHERE a.name LIKE '%sa%' OR a.email LIKE '%sa%'OR a.id LIKE '%sa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias in WHERE clause which is created in SELECT clause because WHERE is executed before SELECT clause. You need to use nested query. Also, you need to look into the way you are comparing totalMember as its an integer and you are comparing it with a string

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT name, email, (SELECT Count(id) FROM members WHERE id = a.id) as totalMember, id

FROM account a
) tab
WHERE
(name LIKE '%sa%' OR email LIKE '%sa%' OR totalMember LIKE '%sa%' OR
 id LIKE '%sa%')
```